# aggregate lines and sum up column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file that contains the following lines :

```html
01323874;291874;-;000000000000003030;2511011999;-;000000000000000000 
01323874;291874;-;000000000012920840;2511011999;+;000002910023874000 
01323872;291872;-;000000000000008750;2511011999;-;000000000000008750 
01323872;291872;+;000000000609396980;          ;+;000000000000000000 
01323778;      ;-;000000000468442930;          ;+;000000000000000000 
01323778;      ;+;000000005166500460;          ;+;000000000000000000
01323778;      ;-;000000000469421100;2511021000;+;000000000469421100 
01323778;291778;-;000000000361156930;2511021000;-;000000000361156930
01323778;      ;-;000000000186088530;2511021000;+;000000000186088530 
01323778;291778;-;000000000017602470;2511021000;-;000000000017602470
```

I would like to aggregate lines based on the first column :

Sum up the values of column 4 , taking into consideration the sign (+/-) in column 3.

Sum up the values of column 7 , taking into consideration the sign (+/-) in column 6.

```html
01323874;291874;-;000000000012923871;2511011999;+;000002910023874000
01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230;2511011999;-;000000000000008750
01323778;291778;+;000000003663788500;2511021000;+;000000000276750230
```

I have succeeded to generate a well formatted lines but couldn't find a way to aggregate them.your help will be very appreciated .

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: First post here the code you already done.

Comment: what about colums 2 and 5?

Comment: Within each group, how is the value in the last column selected? I don't see any pattern. Does it matter?

Answer (score 4):

```
kent$  cat f
01323874;291874;-;000000000000003030;2511011999;-;000000000000000000
01323874;291874;-;000000000012920840;2511011999;+;000002910023874000
01323872;291872;-;000000000000008750;2511011999;-;000000000000008750
01323872;291872;+;000000000609396980;          ;+;000000000000000000
01323778;      ;-;000000000468442930;          ;+;000000000000000000
01323778;      ;+;000000005166500460;          ;+;000000000000000000
01323778;      ;-;000000000469421100;2511021000;+;000000000469421100
01323778;291778;-;000000000361156930;2511021000;-;000000000361156930
01323778;      ;-;000000000186088530;2511021000;+;000000000186088530
01323778;291778;-;000000000017602470;2511021000;-;000000000017602470
```

output

```
kent$  awk -F';' '{a[$1]=(1*$2?$2:a[$1]); b[$1]+=$3=="-"?-$4:$4;
                   c[$1]=(1*$5?$5:c[$1]); d[$1]+=$6=="-"?-$7:$7}
        END{for(x in a)
               printf "%s;%s;%s;%018d;%s;%s;%018d\n",
                        x,a[x],
                        (b[x]>0?"+":"-"),(b[x]<0?-b[x]:b[x]),c[x],
                        (d[x]>0?"+":"-"),(d[x]<0?-d[x]:d[x])}' f
01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230;2511011999;-;000000000000008750
01323778;291778;+;000000003663788500;2511021000;+;000000000276750230
01323874;291874;-;000000000012923870;2511011999;+;000002910023874000
```

Comment: Just for my personal knowledge - what is the purpose of `1*` in there ?

Comment: @fzd you will see if you remove it from the codes. it filtered the black but not empty string out. like `"<spaces>" `

Comment: @kent it works fine thanks but it doesn't handel the case when column 2 or 5 contains only blank space. for example Now I get `01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230;;-;000000000000008750` but it should be `01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230; BLANK SPACE ;-;000000000000008750`

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F';' 'function get_sign(n){ 
               return (n<0)? "-":"+" 
           }
           { 
               a[$1]+=int($3$4); b[$1]+=int($6$7); 
               if ($2*1) fld2[$1]=$2; if ($5*1) fld5[$1]=$5 
           }
           END{ 
               for(i in a) print i, fld2[i], get_sign(a[i]),
               sprintf("%018d",(a[i]>0)? a[i]:a[i]*-1), fld5[i], get_sign(b[i]),
               sprintf("%018d",(b[i]>0)? b[i]:b[i]*-1) 
           }' OFS=';' file
```

The output:

```
01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230;2511011999;-;000000000000008750
01323778;291778;+;000000003663788500;2511021000;+;000000000276750230
01323874;291874;-;000000000012923870;2511011999;+;000002910023874000
```

---

- `function get_sign(n) { ... }` - function, defining whether the numeric argument `n` is positive or negative and returns the respective sign

Comment: it works fine thanks but it doesn't handel the case when column 2 or 5 contains only blank space. for example Now I get `01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230;;-;000000000000008750` but it should be `01323872;291872;+;000000000609388230; BLANK SPACE ;-;000000000000008750`

Comment: @technopathe, that's not true. I've tested that case, when the 2nd column contains only space and it gaves me: `01323872;;+;000000000609388230;2511011999;-;000000000000008750
01323778;;+;000000003663788500;2511021000;+;000000000276750230
01323874;;-;000000000012923870;2511011999;+;000002910023874000
` as expected

Comment: Actually I rather have the white space printed this way ;*********; than this way ;;    * refers to white space

Comment: I have solved the space issue  `awk -F';' 'function get_sign(n){
               return (n<0)? "-":"+"
           }`
           `{a[$1]+=int($3$4); b[$1]+=int($6$7);
               if ($2*1) fld2[$1]=$2; if ($5*1) fld5[$1]=$5
           } END{ for(i in a) print i, fld2[i], get_sign(a[i]), sprintf("%018d",(a[i]>0)? a[i]:a[i]*-1), fld5[i], get_sign(b[i]),
               sprintf("%018d",(b[i]>0)? b[i]:b[i]*-1)}' OFS=';'  F1 > F2 `
  `awk ' BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} {
       $5=sprintf("%10s", $5)
       $2=sprintf("%10s", $2)
       print }' F2 > F3 `  but still need to be shrinked and optimized